# JavaScript Variable Scoped to Parent Request in Asynch Scenario

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are overriding `console.log` in our productive ExpressJS application to add certain fields (e.g. timestamp, sessionid, requestid) as well as send logs to a syslog server.

We are doing this by adding `console.requestId` and `console.sessionId` properties to the global `console` object and then overriding `console.log()` to output these values as well as send logs to syslog. This works fine:

```js
let originalConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function() {
   let args = Array.from(arguments);
   args.unshift(this.sessionId);
   args.unshift(this.requestId);
   originalConsoleLog.log.apply(console, args);
   syslog.log(arguments);
}
app.get('/some-endpoint', async (req, res) => {
   console.requestId = req.header('X-Request-Id');
   console.sessionId = req.session = req.cookies['SESSIONID'];
   let response = await someAsyncProcess();
   console.log('foo');
   req.json(response);
});
```

The problem comes when 2 requests are processed concurrently:

- Request 1 sets requestId/sessionId `REQ1/SESSA`
- Request 1 waits for `someAsyncProcess()`
- Request 2 sets requestId/sessionId `REQ2/SESSB`
- Request 1 logs `REQ2/SESSB foo` when it should log `REQ1/SESSA foo`

So globals (like `console`) are out.

Locals are also out since we do not want to pass some `logger` instance to each and every module.

What we need is a "pseudo global" variable which is scoped to a single request in ExpressJS. Something like closure but to external modules as well:

```js
let logger = new Logger(sessionId, requestId);
function() {
  // I can see logger
  logger.log('hello');
  // This module can't
  let foo = require('foo');
}
```

The idea is that we can set a request and session id on this `logger` variable and all functions/modules/methods called from here on will `console.log` with this session/request id. The variable "belongs" to all code called from the request responder.

We don't want to inject this `logger` instance into every submodule we use but we want to capure `console.log` requests dynamically and inject the relevant local `sessionId` and `requestId`.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you set requestId and sessionId berofe Promise resolves? because if you set it after it might work as intended.
UPD: Yeah didn't think that you might have tons of Promises there)

Comment: We set it as soon as the request comes in - if we don't, the code in `someAsyncProcess()` won't log with the correct sessionId. But I agree with you, setting it afterwards (again) will help in some cases. The issue is `someAsyncProcess()` may again call lots of `async` functions and the sessionId will continuously get overwritten by other request "threads".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use [`async hooks`](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) for this, something like

```js
const asyncHooks = require('async_hooks');
const store = new Map();

const asyncHook = asyncHooks.createHook({
    init: (asyncId, _, triggerAsyncId) => {
        if (store.has(triggerAsyncId)) {
            store.set(asyncId, store.get(triggerAsyncId))
        }
    },
    destroy: (asyncId) => {
        if (store.has(asyncId)) {
            store.delete(asyncId);
        }
    }
});

asyncHook.enable();

const createRequestContext = (sessionId, requestId) => {
    const context = { sessionId, requestId };
    store.set(asyncHooks.executionAsyncId(), context);
    return context;
};

const getRequestContext = () => {
    return store.get(asyncHooks.executionAsyncId());
};


let originalConsoleLog = console.log;

console.log = function() {
   let args = Array.from(arguments);
   const { sessionId, requestId } = getRequestContext();
   args.unshift(sessionId);
   args.unshift(requestId);
   originalConsoleLog.log.apply(console, args);
   syslog.log(arguments);
}

app.get('/some-endpoint', async (req, res) => {
   const requestId = req.header('X-Request-Id');
   const sessionId = req.session = req.cookies['SESSIONID'];
   createRequestContext(requestId, sesscionId);
   let response = await someAsyncProcess();
   console.log('foo');
   req.json(response);
});
```

Comment: Looks spectacular but now my route module and my log module need to share an instance of the store? So I'm back to passing instances to my logging class...

Comment: I stand corrected. I can create a global instance of this context `global.context` and every module has access to the request via `global.context?.getRequestContext()`. This is AWESOME and exactly what I needed!

Comment: Good article here solving this exact issue: https://blog.besson.co/nodejs_async_hooks_to_get_per_request_context/